# event receiver issue

Tags: wss-3.0

I have made event receiver which updates a field in a list, that event receiver is running in the subsite but not the the root site. The event receiver is scope = web.

Can there be some issue with that, also I cannot see

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {


                EventLog.WriteEntry("Windows SharePoint Services 3", errormsg);

            });
```

Please suggest, The site is in WSS 3

Thanks

Comment: could you say more about the event handler target (sync/async, *-ing, *-ed, etc.) ?

Comment: its on ItemAdded

Comment: How have you deployed this? As a feature? Have you activated this in both webs? If you give details on how this was deployed and associated with the structure (list or content type) we'll take it from there.

Comment: I deployed it as a feature on both the sites and on both sites the features are activated, on subsite it works but on its parent site it isnt working.

Comment: It is only meant to work on a custom ID column which will be incremented by +1 everytime the new item is added.. that custom ID column is there on both the sites in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install Sharepoint Manager http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/22762 then browse to your list. See if the event receiver is actually atttached. If not, you have a deployment issue. If yes you have a code issue! :)